# Editing elements inside Magento 2 Invoice Email

Tags: magento

I'd like to know how to change some auto-generated text inside a Magento 2 invoice email. Essentially change the word 'Tax' to 'VAT'. On the front end it is changed and it was done by a developer, using the translation files I believe, but I need to be able to change this last bit in the emails without using the dev as he is away on hols for two weeks.

I have looked in the file structure trying to find a file to edit, but I'm lost.

I can't believe it's this hard to get this seemingly small change made. Would love some help, in idiot speak as I'm not a developer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The transactional Emails such as invoice also get their translation from the .csv in the i18n folder in your theme (`magento-root/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n`).

Look up the exact words to translate in your Email template (it's located under marketing->communication in the magento backend), search for these exact words in the translation file and replace it.

You will probably need to clear your cache when you're done to see the changes.